# How do I show a tooltip with jQuery UI selectmenu for each option?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip, jquery-ui-selectmenu

When i mouse over the options in the `selectmenu` I want to show a custom tooltip.
I can show it for normal buttons. Example:

```
<button id="helpbutton1" title="text in title">Help</button>

$( "#helpbutton1" )
    .button({
        })  
    .tooltip({ 
        content: returnHelpbutton1Content()                     
    });
```

But i can't get it to work with the selectmenu. When i mouse over the different options in the menu I want to be able to see the tooltip for each option. Example:

```
<label for="SelectMenu">Selectmenu example:</label>
    <select name="SelectMenu" id="SelectMenu">
        <option id="option1" title="Tooltip1">option1</option>
        <option id="option2" title="Tooltip2">option2</option>
    </select>

$( "#SelectMenu" ).selectmenu({ 
            width : 100,
            select: function( event, data ) {                   
                console.log("data.item.value: " + this.value);  
            }               
        });

$( "#option1" ).tooltip({ 
    content: returnTooltip1()                   
    });

$( "#option2" ).tooltip({ 
    content: returnTooltip2()                   
    });
```

I use jqueryUI 1.11.0. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/Lv57G/)** of jquery ui tooltip on jquery-ui selectmenu.

JS code:

```
 $(function() {
 var select_id = "speed";
 $( "#"+select_id ).selectmenu({
     open: function( event, ui ) {
         $('li.ui-menu-item').tooltip({
             items:'li',
             //content: "adsdads ad asdadad asd ad adoption"
             content:function(){
                 //console.log($(this).html());
                 return ($(this).html());
             }
         });
     }
 });

 $( "#"+select_id+"-button").tooltip({items: "span", content: 'This is select'});
```

Comment: This example gives you a tooltip for the whole selectmenu. Is it possible to show one for each option if the selectmenu is open? So a tooltip for Slower another one for Slow, ...

Comment: I have edited my code and the demo. Now it shows up tooltip for each option also !! Check it out !

Comment: This example apply tooltips for ALL select menus in the page! If you have more than one jQueryUI select menu, it will apply for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul's solution is applied to *all* select menus in the page. Here's a simpler solution that does not bind to the "open" event, and can be applied to any specific select menu (assuming this object exists and was already initialized as a selectmenu):

```
$('#myselectbox').selectmenu( "menuWidget" ).tooltip({
    items:'li',
    content: function() {
        return ($(this).html());
    }
});
```